# Plot Columns in a Dataframe using ggplot

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a dataframe where each column is a time series. There are a total of 87 columns. 1st column is the time and the 2:87 are the timeseries data

I want to plot time series for all the 86 columns using ggplot. I have used the following code. "data_si" is the data frame

```
> for (i in 2:87) 
plot_[[i]] <- ggplot(data_si, aes(time, i)) + geom_line()
```

The error is

> Error: object 'plot_' not found

Does that mean I need to create a list of columns? If yes, how do I do that? And how can I incorporate it in the loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before the loop, add: `plot_ <- list()`.

Comment: Probably you should use `lapply`? Otherwise you might  get problems with ggplots `aes` evaluation

Comment: @patL I tried this. The command did run but when I tried for plot_2 it shows "object 'plot_2' not found"

Comment: @SankalpMathur In order to access your second plot you have to do `plot_[[2]]` since it is a list.

Comment: You cannot use `i` within `aes` like this. `aes` accepts *only*  column names and also does non-standard evaluation. You could use `aes_string` with its standard evaluation but would still need to iterate over column names instead of numbers: `for (i in names(data_si)[2:87])`